# Spark: balanced tasks but unbalanced executors

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an heavy stage in spark with ~8k tasks and it shows a good computation distribution

[image]

However, this is what I see in the executor aggregated metrics if I sort by Task Time. This is min Task Time

[image]

and this is max

[image]

Why the tasks are balanced in terms of input and execution time while executors are not (i.e. some executors are getting more work than others). Is there a way to avoid this?

In particular, the stage is writing a big dataframe to hdfs with `df.write.format("orc").partitionBy("date", "hour").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).save(path)` and I run on top of yarn

Comment: Which cluster manager do you use?